# Convert nvarchar of a column with dbplyr?

Tags: r, sql-server, dbplyr

Is it possible to replicate the following query in dbplyr:

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(4000), column_name) [column_name]
FROM table_name
```

The 'convert(nvarchar(4000)' bit is what I'm interested in here. I'd guess that this would be outside the scope of dbplyr, but it would be great to know for sure. I'm using SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: `nvarchar(5000)` isn't a valid datatype. The largest length you can declare an `nvarchar` is 4000 characters. For lengths longer than that you have to use a `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: thanks @larnu , I've edited the question accordingly